# Spring Roo - How to override boolean transactional() in RooService annotation

Tags: java, spring-roo

I have a service class that is annotated with `@RooService`. For some reason, my methods inside this service class should not be transactional yet I don't want to move away from `@RooService`. I found that there is a definition in `@RooService` called "`boolean transactional() default true`" that might do the tricks. How do I change this to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@RooService(transactional = false)
```

Read the [tutorial on annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/index.html).